# Display the same author name for all users in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, author

For a Wordpress organization website, I want all the posts to have by default the same author name (the organization name). How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possibilites.

1) Simplest: You only create one author and share the login within the organization

2) You simply do not display the author on your post - why would you do that? It is probably obvious that your organization is the publisher of these pages anyway.

3) Add the following custom code within your Theme or Plugin:

```
add_filter('the_author','its_my_company');

function its_my_company() {
   return 'Organization Name';
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_author/

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is to modify your theme or child theme to display a specific user or name wherever the template does so. In your `single.php` file, look for `the_author()` or `get_the_author()`. Then use something like `get_user_by()` to pull a specific user, or else hard code the value (less ideal, but an option).

Your other option is to manually set it each time, which I could exactly define as making anything "default." Even so, the option exists.

[image]